# Passing values to an arrow function from Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am writing Jest test cases for my application and I have an arrow function

**Product.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Products extends React.Component {
     constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        prodName: '',
        prodID: '',
        brandName: '',
        prodNameHidden: true,
        brandNameHidden: true,
        idHidden: true,
       }
    }
     handleChange = type => (event) => {
          console.log(type)
          if(type == 'add') {
            var key = event.target.name;
            var val = event.target.value;
            switch (key) {
             case "prodName": 
                this.setState({prodNameHidden: true})
             break;
             case "brandName":
                this.setState({brandNameHidden: true})
             break;
             case "prodID":
                this.setState({idHidden: true})
             break
        }
        this.setState({[key]: val});
     }
     else if(type == "edit") {
          //Statements for type:edit
    }
     render() {
       return (
       <div>
         <span hidden={this.state.prodNameHidden} className="inpSpan errSpan">Please enter the product name</span>
                <label className="inpLabel"><span className="inpSpan">* </span>Product Name:</label>
                <input className="inp" type="text" placeholder="Enter the product name" onChange={this.handleChange("add")} name="prodName" value={this.state.prodName}/>

                <span hidden={this.state.brandNameHidden} className="inpSpan errSpan">Please enter the brand name</span>
                <label className="inpLabel"><span className="inpSpan">* </span>Brand Name:</label>
                <input className="inp" type="text" placeholder="Enter the brand name" onChange={this.handleChange("add")} name="brandName" value={this.state.brandName}/>

                <span hidden={this.state.idHidden} className="inpSpan errSpan">Please enter the product ID</span>
                <label className="inpLabel"><span className="inpSpan">* </span>Product ID:</label>
                <input className="inp" type="number" placeholder="Enter the product ID" onChange={this.handleChange("add")} name="prodID" value={this.state.prodID}/>
       </div>
      );
}
export default Product;
```

and in Jest, I need to test the handleChange() with dummy values.

**Product.test.js**

```
//have initialized wrapper in beforeEach()
it("Should do something", () => {
    dummyEvent = {
        target: {
           value: "dummyValue",
           name: "dummyName"
        }
   }
   wrapper.setState({
        prodName: '',
        prodID: '',
        brandName: '',
        prodNameHidden: ,
        brandNameHidden: true,
        idHidden: true,
    })
    wrapper.instance().handleChange("add", dummyEvent);
    expect(wrapper.state().prodName).toBe("dummyValue");
})
```

But I am not able to test it because, JEST is not able to find the function

**Test Result**

Expected: dummyValue

Received: ' '

Any help is be appreciated.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. But you shouldn't access the instance or call methods directly; test the *behaviour*, not the implementation.

Comment: What does your component look like? You should be simulating an event, not manually invoking the method

Comment: You should not test implementations in react. Rather test the expected outcome "visually". Check out Kent C Dodds [post on testing implementations](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details). There are several more blog posts why you should'nt do this.

Comment: @prohit You should. Otherwise Enzyme wouldn't exist. Or not. It depends on the case. Please, don't be dogmatic. There are good use cases for isolated unit tests and blackbox functional tests.

Comment: Apologies for the "Not so clear" code. I have edited it and hope, this will be clear